# What does 'culture' mean in this sentence?

Tags: terminology, meaning-in-context

> ...which is often used when the physician does not (or cannot) perform a **culture** to determine the actual bacterium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/culture):

> the act or process of cultivating living material (as bacteria or viruses) in prepared nutrient media; also : a product of such cultivation